# Where did Fisk's resources come from?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil

Is it said anywhere during season 1 from where Fisk got his money and education?

Viewers see his history when he is 12 years old living in NY with his poor family. Then he is sent to some *relatives* and reappears in NY after ~30 years with wealth and connections, knowing Japanese and Mandarin etc. You could say that he is very intelligent, educated himself and has risen to his position. On the other hand, the show also presents him as a fury-driven brute who exposes his entire operation because of the woman.

I did not read many comics with Kingpin but I know that the above characteristics are consistent with comics. On the other hand as far as I know, in the comics he was a gangster from the beginning. In the series he is portrayed as clumsy, shy kid who probably wants to be an astronaut. I find it hard to imagine how he was able to become a criminal mastermind.

Did the series state something about his past after leaving NY? Did I miss something? Who were these *relatives*? Maybe they were relevant to him becoming mobster?

Comment: He told Vanessa after his father died he went to live on a farm with relatives. I don't think they said anything in the show about where he got his wealth or experience. Part of his persona in the show was that nobody knew anything about him

Answer (score 7):

Although it is never stated outright in the show, it is heavily implied that Fisk is a self-made man, a man who earned his money over the years; also you have to take into account his drug dealings with the Chinese and the Russians as well.

Answer (score 2):

The same way any other crime boss gains their fortune.  Through illegal activities combined with legal business dealings and being ruthless.